# HTTP Error 500.19 , website with framework 3.5 on windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, frameworks, .net-3.5

i publish my website and install iis on windows 7, and add my website into this address :
c --> inetpub --> wwwroot 
and add permission to my folder (IIS_IUSRS , IUSR) but now when type this address (http://localhost/publish/default.aspx)(Publish folder is in wwwroot folder) in address bar of browser see this error :

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

plz help me!!

Comment: Turn off custom errors and post detailed IIS error message here.

Comment: in web.config, customerror is OFF, and iis error is :

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error : The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of googling may help you a lot (i heve seen this answer on Google before), second, this error is more likely because you don't have ASP.NET enabled in IIS, to enable open the Control Panel, go to Programs and Features, then go to Internet Information Services-> World Wide Web Services-> Application Development Features and enable ASP.NET, then click Ok and wait for the features to be enabled, also be sure you have installed the .NET Framework.

Comment: i before research about my problem, and when i install iis, select asp.net. but iis error continue :(

Comment: Well, if you selected ASP.NET then probably installed the .NET Framework before installing IIS, so you may need to register the .NET Framework, for this open a Command Prompt and go to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Your Framework version", and run the aspnet_regiis -i command, do this for every .NET Framework you need in ascending order (don't forget the 64 bits versions also)

Comment: id dont have aspnet_regiis in version 3.5 folder, but i have that in version 4!! now what do i ?

Comment: Not every version of the .NET Framework includes an aspnet_regiis application, so if it doesn't include it, skip it to the next. The reason: they're minor versions, so they run a top of the last full version (in the case of .NET 3.5, .NET 2.0)